# Ellipsize text before dynamic width element

Tags: html, css, image

I would like multi-line text to be ellipsized on the last line before a dynamically sized element. And that the element is right aligned.

eg (with XX representing the optional image with variable width)

No dynamic element:

```
This is a short
paragraph with
text that ov...
```

With an element and long text:

```
This is a short
paragraph with
text th...  XX
```

With an element and shorter text:

```
This is a short
paragraph that
wraps       XX
```

```
This is a short
paragraph
            XX
```

I've tried various ways including putting the image into a container with `display: inline-block` or positioning it with `position:absolute` but I can't make it work as above. I can't even make it work left aligned with the text.

The paragraph has this css:

```
.description {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  line-clamp: 3;
}
```

And currently the html looks like:

```
<div class="description">
  <span>the paragraph text</span>
  <span class="status-icons"><img 1/><img 2/></span>
</div>
```

Ideally I'd like to do this with just css, but happy to use js if required

Comment: You would basically need the image to behave as if it was floated, but on the bottom instead on the top - and that is a feature `float` doesn't provide. Maybe(!) you can somehow achieve this by using [`shape-outside`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside), if you can "calculate" what the shape has to look like, to not restrict the text width at all in the part that would come "above" the image, and then restrict it to "spare out" the image dimensions on the lower end. Since you apparently want to limit it to a maximum of three lines of text, that _might_ work ...

Comment: *Based on CBroe's comment and the duplicate questions I was able to* --> so your question **is** a duplicate because you were able to find a solution thanks to it (and don't include the solution within the quesiont)